# Rails Facebooker image_submit_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, facebooker

I have a typical form_for for registering user. But in the end I would like to have an option to submit data with fb_login_button. So I could save user's (manually entered) data as well as data that facebook sends me in one swing. Is that possible? If not, can I get user's facebook data wihout redirecting to new page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just specify a javascript callback:

```
<%= fb_login_button 'document.nameOfYourForm.submit();' %>
```